# Checkbox não envia valor "False" quando efetuado Submit - Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, checkbox

Tenho um projeto mvc no asp.net core e estou tendo problemas ao efetuar um submit. Bom eu "seto" as propriedades da minha Model PessoaContatoCorreioEletronicoViewModel com "False" e os Checkbox aparecem desmarcados na tela.

```
return new PessoaContatoCorreioEletronicoViewModel
{
    UsarParaNotaFiscalEmitida = false,
    UsarParaOrdemCompra = false,
    UsarParaPedidoVenda = false,
    UsarParaMarketing = false
};
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que quando eu faço um submit, a classe fica com valor NULL... É como se os asp.net reconhecesse que nenhum checkbox fora marcado e definiu a classe como null. Se eu marcar pelo menos um checkbox funciona... Só que eu gostaria que todos os checkbox assumissem um valor padrão FALSE para não acontecer esse problema. Como faço?

Se eu não selecionar nenhum dos Checkbox:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu Selecionar pelo menos um dos checkbox:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<a class="dropdown-item" role="menuitem"><input data-plugin="switchery" type="checkbox" data-size="small" class="ckb-usar-nf-emitida" data-val="true" value="true" checked="@(Model.PessoaContatoCorreioEletronicoViewModel.UsarParaNotaFiscalEmitida)" id="PessoaContatoCorreioEletronicoViewModel_@(indice)_UsarParaNotaFiscalEmitida" name="PessoasContatosViewModel[@indice].PessoaContatoCorreioEletronicoViewModel.UsarParaNotaFiscalEmitida" /> Usar para NF Emitida</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" role="menuitem"><input data-plugin="switchery" type="checkbox" data-size="small" class="ckb-usar-ordem-compra" data-val="true" value="true" checked="@(Model.PessoaContatoCorreioEletronicoViewModel.UsarParaOrdemCompra)" id="PessoaContatoCorreioEletronicoViewModel_@(indice)_UsarParaOrdemCompra" name="PessoasContatosViewModel[@indice].PessoaContatoCorreioEletronicoViewModel.UsarParaOrdemCompra" /> Usar para Ordem de Compra</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" role="menuitem"><input data-plugin="switchery" type="checkbox" data-size="small" class="ckb-usar-pedido-venda" data-val="true" value="true" checked="@(Model.PessoaContatoCorreioEletronicoViewModel.UsarParaPedidoVenda)" id="PessoaContatoCorreioEletronicoViewModel_@(indice)_UsarParaPedidoVenda" name="PessoasContatosViewModel[@indice].PessoaContatoCorreioEletronicoViewModel.UsarParaPedidoVenda" /> Usar para Pedido de Venda</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" role="menuitem"><input data-plugin="switchery" type="checkbox" data-size="small" class="ckb-usar-marketing" data-val="true" value="true" checked="@(Model.PessoaContatoCorreioEletronicoViewModel.UsarParaMarketing)" id="PessoaContatoCorreioEletronicoViewModel_@(indice)_UsarParaMarketing" name="PessoasContatosViewModel[@indice].PessoaContatoCorreioEletronicoViewModel.UsarParaMarketing" /> Usar para Marketing</a>
<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
```

Comment: Se usa qual aspnet?

Comment: Asp.net Core 2.0

Comment: Use as tag razor que é melhor. acontece isso porque não tem o que instanciar para essa classe, talvez se você instanciar no construtor possa arrumar isso, tente fazer esse teste